# Source for blockchain dump in machine readable format

Tags: blockchain

Where to get blockchain dump in machine readable format. Text files of JSON will be perfect . I found PSQL database at http://dumps.webbtc.com/bitcoin/ . Any other source?

Comment: you can use the official client to download the raw blockchain. it has a nice JSON-RPC api as well.

Comment: @LucaMatteis thanks, can I export raw blockchain using JSON-RPC to flat files?

Comment: Yes. `getblock`. Blocks are stored on disk in the network format which is absolutely trivial to parse yourself anyway.